# What is 2SLS estimator with three instruments?

Tags: regression, econometrics, instrumental-variables, 2sls

Given the following model,
$$y_i = a + bx_i +e_i$$
It's known that $Cov(e, x ) \neq 0$, so we are going to use 2SLS method. We have three variables $v_1, v_2, v_3$.
What is the formula for the slope $\hat b$?

Comment: I guess that it will be difficult to come up with more informative expression than the general 2SLS formula $(X'PX)^{-1}X'Py$?

Comment: Ok, thank you! Am I right that $P = V(V^TV)^{-1} V^T$ where $V$ is a matrix consisting of three columns $v_1, v_2, v_3$?

Comment: Indeed, the projection matrix when projecting on the instruments

Comment: Good. I wasn't sure if $V$ consists of $v_i$ as rows or columns...